# Extjs store.sync error with multiple instance of same model

Tags: javascript, extjs4

I have a problem with store.sync()

I use multiple form (multiple instance of same model in different tab) with the same model/store but with not all the fields of the model.

When i use store.sync the store work, i have the record in my database and the result is success:true !

I load the form :

```
if(modeleActif == 'UniteDeTemps') {

    var form = Ext.getCmp('Form'+modeleActif+'1');
    var record = Ext.create('ModuleGestion.model.'+modeleActif);
    form.loadRecord(record);

    var form = Ext.getCmp('Form'+modeleActif+'2');
    var record = Ext.create('ModuleGestion.model.'+modeleActif);
    form.loadRecord(record);

    var form = Ext.getCmp('Form'+modeleActif+'3');
    var record = Ext.create('ModuleGestion.model.'+modeleActif);
    form.loadRecord(record);

    var form = Ext.getCmp('Form'+modeleActif+'4');
    var record = Ext.create('ModuleGestion.model.'+modeleActif);
    form.loadRecord(record);



}
```

My controller action:

```
if(modeleActif == 'UniteDeTemps') {

modeleUDTActif = Ext.getCmp('TabUniteDeTempsForm').getActiveTab().id;
Type_O_J_S_M = modeleUDTActif.substr(15,modeleActif.length);

var form = Ext.getCmp('Form'+modeleActif+Type_O_J_S_M);
var store = this['get'+modeleActif+'Store']();

record = form.getRecord();
values = form.getValues();

if (form.isValid()) {

    record.set(values);

    store.add(record);

    store.sync({
        success: function(batch, options) {
            store.load();
        },
        failure: function(batch, options) {
            Ext.Msg.alert("Erreur",batch.proxy.getReader().jsonData.message);
        }
    });                    

}

}
```

My model

```
Ext.define('ModuleGestion.model.UniteDeTemps', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    idProperty: 'idUniteDeTemps',

    fields: [
        {
            name: 'idUniteDeTemps'
        },
        {
            name: 'UniteDeTemps'
        },
        {
            name: 'Type_O_J_S_M'
        },
        {
            name: 'Type_M'
        },
        {
            name: 'Occurence'
        },
        {
            name: 'RepetitionJ'
        },
        {
            name: 'RepetitionS'
        },
        {
            name: 'Jours'
        },
        {
            name: 'Mois'
        },
        {
            name: 'Quantieme'
        },
        {
            name: 'Numero'
        }
    ]
});
```

My form:

```
{
    xtype: 'form',
    border: false,
    id: 'FormUniteDeTemps1',
    bodyPadding: 10,
    title: '',
    items: [
        {
        xtype: 'textfield',
        width: 305,
        fieldLabel: 'Nom',
        name: 'UniteDeTemps'
        },
        {
        xtype: 'hiddenfield',
        fieldLabel: 'Label',
        name: 'idUniteDeTemps'
        },
        {
        xtype: 'hiddenfield',
        fieldLabel: 'Label',
        name: 'Type_O_J_S_M'
        },
        {
        xtype: 'numberfield',
        fieldLabel: 'Nombre d\'occurences',
        labelWidth: 150,
        name: 'Occurence'
        }
    ]
}
```